# How to make a safari style Yosemite add tab button

Tags: objective-c, macos

First of all, I am so sorry for my bad English.

Secondly I would like to ask you, how can I set a toolbar item ( custom view ) at the bottom right corner of the toolbar( like the add tab button in safari Yosemite ). I have already found the NSTitlebarAcessoryViewController Class and i have set with that my Custom Tab view. But I cannot find how to set my add tab button at the position I told you, when my tab view is hidden.

I must also tell you that I am a total newbie.

Thank you in advance for your time. :-)